# Python relative imports do not work in VS Code but do in PyCharm

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, import, module, python-import

I'm trying to import `db/connectdb.py` in `model/task.py`, both `model` and `db` folder are in the main project folder.

When I try `from db.connectdb import ConnectDb` I get

> ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'db'

When I try `from ..db.connectdb import ConnectDb` I get

> ImportError: attempted relative import with no known parent package

Everything works well in PyCharm.

I tried to add `__init__.py` to each folder but it is giving the same issue.

This is `connectdb.py`:

```
import os
import sqlite3


class ConnectDb():
    def __init__(self):
        db_path = os.path.join(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)), 'app.db')
        if os.path.isfile(db_path):
            self.db = sqlite3.connect(db_path)
        else:
            #self.db = None
            print("non")

    def get_connection(self):
        return self.db
```

This is `task.py`:

```
#from ..db.connectdb import ConnectDb or
from db.connectdb import ConnectDb
class Tasks():
    def __init__(self):
        self.db = ConnectDb().get_connection()

    def get_all_tasks(self):
        return self.db.execute("Select * from tasks").fetchall()


t = Tasks()
print(t.get_all_tasks())
```

This is the folder strcture:

[image]

Comment: How do you execute the code?

Comment: execute it from the run button in the same file look at the cmd
E:\PROJECTS\python\random\projects\pys6\todolist>"C:/Program Files/Python310/python.exe" e:/PROJECTS/python/random/projects/pys6/todolist/model/task.py
the root folder is todolist

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can solve this by adding the current directory to the path:

```
import os
import sys
root = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.path.realpath(__file__))) # the line help you to get current file path
sys.path.append(root) # the line add the file path to path list
```

If you want to add other dir to the path you can repeat:

```
sys.path.append(your_dir)
```

with your custom directory. But for your project, you only need to add the db folder parrent's folder to path.

Final code must be like below:

```
import os
import sys
root = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.path.realpath(__file__))) # the line help you to get current file path
sys.path.append(root) # the line add the file path to path list

from db.connectdb import ConnectDb
class Tasks():
.
.
.
```

Comment: I tried this but it gives the same problem i guess it is because we are adding the path of model directory whiche is not the root folder for project

Comment: try to add path with static directory, for example: sys.path.append('/home/user/parent/'). or try: "root = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.path.realpath(__file__)))" , this help you to get real root directory instead of model dir.

Comment: i'm edited the solution, now select root folder instead of model folder

Comment: with this edit its works

Answer (score 0):

When you execute task.py with VS code, it will look for the folder db inside the folder model, and will not find it...You can put the folder db inside the model folder, it should work.(I think there is another method but I don't know it...)